# Sails.js GET http method not bringing results

Tags: postgresql, http, get, sails.js

I have records in my PostgreSQL Database.
From Postman (or anywhere) i'm typing `localhost:1337/author/` with GET method and receive an empty JSON array `[]` with status `200`, but when i type `localhost:1337/author/2` i receive the row with ID 2

```
"books": [],
"names_surnames": "Author Name",
"biography": "asdkhasdfg",
"id": 2,
"createdAt": "2018-01-23T19:37:49.000Z",
"updatedAt": "2018-01-23T19:37:49.000Z"
```

POST works well and GET with ID specified too, but when i want list all the rows i receive an empty array, why?

EDIT: before it worked fine, this is the unique model with this problem

EDIT2: This only happends when i edit the `config/blueprints.js` file and set `defaultLimit: -1` for unlimit the num of results (i need to unlimit the results)

Comment: Have you made any changes to index route or controller for author?

Comment: @Glen No, it still exacly the same since i generated it with `Sails generate api`

Comment: Can you please reproduce this with a github repo? It is a very weird behavior indeed...

Comment: This only happends when i set `defaultLimit: -1` for unlimit the results but with defaultLimit property greater than 0, it works. Is this a desired behavior?